# What movie is Asajj Ventress in, if any?

Tags: star-wars

Is Asajj Ventress in any of the Star Wars movies? I really want to know.

If so which movie?

Comment: I don't think she was, off the top of my head

Comment: Perhaps you could explain who she is and why she should be in any of the movies?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Her sole feature film appearance is *The Clone Wars* CG-animated film, where she was voiced by [Nika Futterman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0296546/?ref_=tt_cl_t6#actress-tt1185834). She also appeared in some of the *LEGO Star Wars* TV movies. She has not appeared in any live action film.

According to [her IMDB character page](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000028/?ref_=fn_al_ch_1), these are all of her movie appearances:

- [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1185834/) (2008), voiced by Nika Futterman
- [*LEGO Star Wars: The Padawan Menace*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2005268/) (2011), voiced by Nika Futterman
- [*LEGO Star Wars: The Yoda Chronicles - Menace of the Sith*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3096794/) (2013), voiced by [Trish Pattendon](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm5849431/)
- [*LEGO Star Wars: The Yoda Chronicles - Attack of the Jedi*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3304916/) (2013), voiced by Trish Pattendon

Note that the last three are all TV movies; the last two are part of the *LEGO Star Wars: The Yoda Chronicles* trilogy of ["animated specials"](http://www.starwars.com/news/announcing-lego-star-wars-the-yoda-chronicles).